# scaling the output in asy environment in latex

Tags: scaling, asymptote

In section "3.4 High-resolution rasterized images" of the document "An Asymptote tutorial" two methods are suggested for improving resolution. One method is adding the command `shipout(scale(4.0)currentpicture.fit());` at the end of the code, but it's required that the image to be **scaled back down**.

How can I scale down the output image in inline environment in latex? I have attached a minimal latex file.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\begin{document}
Some text
\begin{asy}
settings.render = 8;
settings.outformat = "pdf";
import three;
unitsize(2.5cm);
label("Some text", (0,0,0), S); 
draw((0,0,0) -- (1,1,1), linewidth(2pt));
shipout(scale(2.0) * currentpicture.fit());
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

Thanks,
Abbas

Comment: That's an excellent question. I *think* you can use the `width` option for the `asy` environment, although that also inserts a `width` command at the beginning of the asymptote code. If you switch to the `asypictureB` package you can use any `graphics` package keyword for the `asypicture` environment, but you won't have inline functionality.

Comment: If you need a workaround for a single image then you can edit the file `yourfile-1.tex` that `asy` produces and change `\includegraphics[hiresbb]{\ASYprefix\jobname-1+0_0.pdf}` into `\includegraphics[hiresbb,scale=0.5]{\ASYprefix\jobname-1+0_0.pdf}`.

Comment: @CharlesStaats thanks for your reply. Unfortunately the `width` command does not do any good in this case. For `asypictureB` package, I get the error `I can't write on file "filename-compile_asy.bat"`. Can you please advise how to solve this issue?

Comment: got it. I have to use `-shell-escape` option for `asypictureB` package and it solved the issue. Thank you!